# I have a like system on my site

Tags: php

I have a like system where everytime you click on the favorite the button adds a value to the database with the `userid` and `msgid` liked. On page load, it will check what got liked and what didn't using mysql. If liked it will show the unlike button. But I want to show how many people have liked the `msgid`. I don't know how to define the form which is created for the message.

Here is my code:

```
function listfav($msgid){
  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fav` WHERE `msgid`='$msgid'");
  $q1 = mysql_num_rows($q);
  $n = 0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1)){
    $n += 1;
  }
  return $n.' People favorited this!';
}
```

Comment: Totally don't understand what are you doing. What form do you want?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Indeed, **DO NOT** use `mysql_*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function listfav($msgid)
{
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS likes FROM `fav` WHERE `msgid`='$msgid'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
    $likes = number_format($row['likes'], 0); // add formatting to the number
    return "{$likes} People favorited this!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `fav` WHERE `msgid`='$msgid'
```